# Contour detection based on 4-connectivity using `findContours()` from OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, contour, detection, data-processing

the `findContours()` function from the OpenCV library does not allow you to customize the selection of contours based on 4-connectivity. I checked on a test image: [image: test image] all the modes of this function that we can adjust and they all seem to use 8-connectivity for contours detection, as they select the object in the image as 1 whole contour.
If we use 4-connectivity, the neighbors of white pixels on the diagonal would not be taken into account and the function would select two contours in the image, which is what I want to reach.

I tried to send different parameters to `findContours()`, I read documentation and forums, but as I realized OpenCV can't achieve 4-connectivity. Then I wrote my naive algorithm for selecting contours based on 4-connectivity in python, but I had difficulties with counting the number of selected contours and nested contours.

Please tell me what I can use to solve my problem? If there are any other functions in OpenCV library that could help me to select contours based on 4-connectivity or will I have to write an algorithm myself? In my project I need to select contours of 1 and 2 hierarchies and count their number.

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

def is_4_connected(pixel, neighbor):
    return np.abs(pixel - neighbor) == 1

# uploading file with data
with open('text_data.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    data = [[float(value) for value in line.strip().split()] for line in lines]

# Converting data to NumPy array
image = np.array(data)
max_value = np.amax(image)
threshold = max_value / 2
# Image binarization (threshold value can be adjusted)
binary_image = np.where(image < threshold, 0, 1)
contour_count = np.zeros((255, 255))
c = []
# Creating an image with contours based on 4-connectivity
contour_image = np.zeros_like(binary_image)
binary_image = binary_image.astype(np.uint8)
for y in range(1, binary_image.shape[0] - 1):
        c.append(len(contour_count[y]))
        for x in range(1, binary_image.shape[1] - 1):
                if binary_image[y, x] == 0:
                        if binary_image[y - 1, x] == 1 or binary_image[y + 1, x] == 1 or binary_image[y, x - 1] == 1 or binary_image[y, x + 1] == 1:
                                contour_image[y, x] = 1
                elif binary_image[y, x] == 1:
                # Checking 4-connectivity with neighboring pixels
                        if not is_4_connected(binary_image[y, x], binary_image[y - 1, x]) and \
                        not is_4_connected(binary_image[y, x], binary_image[y + 1, x]) and \
                        not is_4_connected(binary_image[y, x], binary_image[y, x - 1]) and \
                        not is_4_connected(binary_image[y, x], binary_image[y, x + 1]):
                     # If there is no 4-connectivity with any neighboring pixel, it is a new contour
                                        contour_count[y][x] = 1
        
        
        
        
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binary_image, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
level1_count = 0
level2_count = 0
for i, cnt in enumerate(contours):
        if hierarchy[0][i][3] == -1:
# First level contour
                level1_count += 1
        else:
# 2nd level contour
                level2_count += 1

# Print result
print("number of 1st level contours:", len(c))
print("number of 2nd level contours:", level2_count)
 
# Displaying an image with outlines
plt.imshow(contour_image, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Function `connectedComponents()` can select connectivity 8 or 4. So, using this first and then extracting contour for each region is conseivable? (But I don't know how to recognize hierarchies)